# How do I maintain format when exporting from Power BI to Excel?

Tags: excel, powerbi, export-to-excel

When exporting data from Power BI to Excel, the format for the "SOS" column keeps changing. As you can see in A:2 the "000" value changes to "0." Is there a way to export it so that nothing changes? I did ensure that in Power BI it is formatted as TEXT before exporting.
(Note: This Power BI dataset is NOT published. I am not sure if that makes a difference)

What I see in Power BI

| sos | Part | Demand | Extended Sell | *Q1 Demand | *Q2 Demand | *Q3 Demand | *Q4 Demand |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 000 | 20R1370 | 28 |  | 12 | 8 | 4 | 4 |
| 000 | 1535720 | 1243 |  | 9 | 1026 | 188 | 20 |
| 000 | 20R6319 | 14 |  | 6 | 4 | 4 |  |
| 530 | FAI/FA2 | 1619 |  | 580 | 415 | 404 | 220 |
| 000 | 20R1864 | 64 |  | 12 | 52 |  |  |
| 500 | 2459772 | 2 |  | 2 |  |  |  |

What I see after exporting to Excel

| SOS | Part | Demand | Extended Sell | *Q1 Demand | *Q2 Demand | *Q3 Demand | *Q4 Demand |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 20R1370 | 28 |  | 12 | 8 | 4 | 4 |
| 0 | 1535720 | 1243 |  | 9 | 1026 | 188 | 20 |
| 0 | 20R6319 | 14 |  | 6 | 4 | 4 |  |
| 530 | FA1/FA2 | 1619 |  | 580 | 415 | 404 | 220 |
| 0 | 20R1864 | 64 |  | 12 | 52 |  |  |
| 500 | 2459772 | 2 |  | 2 |  |  |  |

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So what I understand as you did not publish the Power BI report, you are trying to export the data from Power BI Desktop. This process returns a CSV and indeed, you can't format type on a CSV file correctly. Instead, try to publish your Power BI into your workspace, export your data from this published report, and you'll have an excel file correctly formatted.

Reference : https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Export-to-excel/td-p/1012366